# handling inputs when iterating over objects in simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So i have a form which i want to update the existing members of a membership.
I have the form, then inside that im iterating over each member and have a hidden_field_tag with the members_uid that i want to submit.

However when i go into the controller, only the last member uid has been submitted. I believe this is because the :patient_uid within the hidden_field_tag is the same for every member submission due to the iteration, therefore it only takes the last one.

My code is below:

```html
  <%= simple_form_for [@membership_policy], url: admin_membership_policy_add_members_to_policy_path(@membership_policy) do |f| %>
   <% @membership_policy.members.each do |member| %>
                         <div class="form-group form-group__search <%= 'has-error' if local_assigns[:errors]&.any? %>">
            <%= hidden_field_tag :patient_uid, member.patient.uid, class: "patient_uid" %>
                         </div>
   <% end %>
       <%= f.button :submit, value: "Save", data: { disable_with: t('common.processing') }, class: "hero-button btn_light_turquoise font-weight-500", style: "margin: -5px 0 0 5px;" %>
  <% end %>
```

I've also tried doing:

```
  <%= hidden_field_tag "patient_uid_#{member.patient.id}", member.patient.uid, class: "patient_uid" %>
```

However i'm unable to access each uid in the controller by doing this.
So basically i just want to be able to submit the form and have a collection of the member_uids in an array or something similar so i can access them.
Apologies if this doesnt make sense.

[image]
This is what is returned when i interpolate an id into the uid. I'm not sure how to access each value when the keys have unique names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you tried at the last should have done it if they all have different value in name tag. This problem occurs when name tag of different fields holds the same value. Let's look at the below example -

```
<% (0..5).each do |a| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "patient_uid", a, class: "patient_uid" %>
<% end %>
```

In this case it will always submit the last field which have the value 5 in it. But if you change it like below -

```
<% (0..5).each do |a| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "patient_uid_#{a}", a, class: "patient_uid" %>
<% end %>
```

Then it will submit all the fields as all of them have different value in name tag.

Please inspect and check if the name tag in the loop are all being the same. Make each one unique, and that should solve your problem.

**For the second edit of your questions**

If you want them in an array you have to make the name tag into something that can accept an array of values. Try the below -

```
<% (0..5).each do |a| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "patient_uid[]", a, class: "patient_uid" %>
<% end %>
```

This way it will insert all the values in the array and you can access the array as `params[:patient_uid]`.

Comment: thanks for you answer. So yes this does work however, i am unable to select the params in the controller as each param has a unique name now. Is there a way to get around this? I have added an image of params to my quesiton